# What is the integral of $e^x a^x$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Can you confirm that my answer below is correct?

$$\int (a^x e^x)dx $$

My attempt:

$$\int a^x e^x \, dx = \int (ae)^x \, dx $$ 
$$\int a^x e^x \, dx = \frac{(ae)^x}{\ln(ae)} + C $$
$$\int a^x e^x \, dx = \frac{a^xe^x}{\ln(ae)} + C $$

Comment: @jeel they share the same exponent, recall if $\frac{a^x}{b^x}$ share the same exponent, can be written as $(\frac{a}{b})^x$

Comment: $\forall a \neq e^{-1}$

Comment: Good point, definitely forgot.

Comment: To confirm this approach is correct when $a>0$, $a\ne1/e$, you might want to define $b=\log a$, then you are after $\int (e^b)^xe^xdx=e^{(b+1)x}dx=\frac1{b+1}e^{(b+1)x}=\frac1{(\log a)+1}(e^b)^xe^x=\ldots$

Comment: Differentiating is the best way to verify that an integral is correct. You should have enough confidence to do such things on your own rather than posting a question.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, I can confirm that your answer above is correct.

Comment: @Qwerty Thanks for your time. The author's question is "Can you confirm that my answer below is correct?", which I quite elegantly answered.

Comment: That should be a comment. Notice that there are **more detailed _comments_** than your answer. Please edit and provide some detail so that others (less experienced) can benefit. At least tell why it is correct.

Comment: @Qwerty: The truth is, it is very complicated to know what to answer this kind of question. Clearly the OP's work is correct, therefore Kenny Lau's answer is correct too (what work should one show, when the task is to simply verify and validate someone elese's work?). On the other hand, I agree that the answer is quite short and should have been posted as a comment. But then, if everybody confirmed the correctness of the OP's work in comments and nobody wrote any answer, the question would figure as unanswered, and this is avoided on MSE. I don't understand, though, the three upvotes...